# iTextSharp: Stamp rotated/placed incorrectly

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am implementing another app that makes use of stamping using iTextsharp 7. I've had this issue on multiple instances. My stamping code resembles the following:

```
 public Stamper(PdfDocument _doc, Rectangle _rect)
    {
        doc = _doc;
        Location = _rect;
    }

    public void StampPDF()
    {
        PdfDocument srcDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(Settings.Default.DefaultAppearance.SignStamp));
        // Create FormXObject and Canvas

        PdfFormXObject page = srcDoc.GetFirstPage().CopyAsFormXObject(doc);
        //Extract Page Dimensions
        float xWidth = srcDoc.GetFirstPage().GetCropBox().GetWidth();
        float xHeight = srcDoc.GetFirstPage().GetCropBox().GetHeight();
        //Better safe than sorry....
        double ratio = xHeight / xWidth;
        ratio = (float)ratio;

        float scaledXHeight = Location.GetHeight();
        float scaledXWidth = (float)(scaledXHeight / ratio * 1.0);



        //Rectangle location = new Rectangle(crop.GetLeft(), crop.GetBottom(), scaledXWidth , scaledXHeight );


        PdfStampAnnotation stamp = new PdfStampAnnotation(Location).SetStampName(new PdfName(Settings.Default.DefaultAppearance.SignName+" Signature"));
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(doc.GetFirstPage().NewContentStreamBefore(), doc.GetFirstPage().GetResources(), doc);

       // canvas.AddXObject(page,location.GetLeft(),location.GetBottom(),page.GetWidth());
        stamp.SetNormalAppearance(page.GetPdfObject());
        stamp.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
        doc.GetFirstPage().AddAnnotation(stamp);


        srcDoc.Close();
```

Noting that I am merging another PDF as my stamp. Once I try to create a Rectangle to a specific slot, my stamp ends up being either OVER-STRETCHED , or ROTATED 90 degrees. I suspect that it is a consequence of the merged PDF having a rotation that is non-zero. However, even setting it's rotation to 0 doesn't fix the problem. Moreover, the issue is exacerbated if the page I am stamping on is rotated, using a reference point like the CropBox simply fails and stamps in an unintended area and orientation.

**EDIT**: Updated code to reflect my exact situation. The function is receiving and already existing (hardcoded) Rectangle called Location and is expected to stamp inside it while maintaining the correct proportions.

How do you compensate for the rotation issue?

Comment: How are you merging or creating the pages in your new document? This does indeed look like a problem with mismatched rotations, and you're dealing with low-level methods, there's a good chance there might be a better solution using some high-level methods

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck 
I wish I knew of a high level method to do this, please let me know if you have any. As for the documents, I am reading existing pdfs - the rotation issue exists mostly because some of them are scanned PDFs. I updated my post to show the exact code I am using in this situation, please refer to that.